# View is expecting for viewmodel while List item has been passed to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Error::

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProjDAL.Models.ViewModels.EmpViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ProjDAL.Models.ViewModels.EmpViewModel'.

I am working on a mvc application. For one view which basically has a functionality for multiple parameter search. I am using same view for get and post method... It means i am passing 1 or more parameters to the textboxes and fetching the result using linq and mapping to a datatable.
After passing the parameters, the values are going to the controller and fetching the exact result using linq but the problem is coming when i am trying to map the linq result-set to my view.

Here is the code for the project -

Controller -

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EmpSearch([Bind(Include = "employee,EmpID,PAN")] Get_EmpDetails_Result  get_EmpDetails_Result)
        {

            var result = from emp in dbCollections.Employees
                         join nat in dbCollections.NationalID on emp.EmpID equals nat.EmpID
                         select new EmpViewModel   
                         {
                             PAN = nat.pan,
                             EmpID = emp.EmpID,
                             employee = emp.Name
                         };

            var searchRes = result
                            .Where(s => s.PAN.Contains(get_EmpDetails_Result.pan)
                                     || s.EmpID.Contains(get_EmpDetails_Result.empid)
                                     || s.employee.Contains(get_EmpDetails_Result.employee));

            var modelSys = searchRes.ToList();
            return View(modelSys);
        }
```

View ::::

```
@model NewProjDAL.Models.ViewModels.EmpViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "empDetails";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
//////////// this part is for the multiple criteria search 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>By EmpID</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GetEmpDetails.FirstOrDefault().empid, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>By PAN</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GetEmpDetails.FirstOrDefault().pan, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>By Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GetEmpDetails.FirstOrDefault().employee, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions center">
            <button type="submit" data-animation="pulse" class="btn btn-lg font-medium-1 btn-outline-teal mb-1 block-multiple-msgs buttonAnimation">
                <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Go
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>
}

//////////////////////////////this part is to fetch the result of the previously mentioned multiple search

                        @if (Model.EmpDetails.Count != 0)
                        {
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dom-jQuery-events compact" id="DataTbl">
                                    <thead class="navbar-dark navbar-dark bg-blue-grey white">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                employee
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                PAN
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                empid
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach (var item in Model.GetEmpDetails)
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.employee)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PAN)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.empid)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's told you exactly what the problem is. You've set up the view to accept a single EmpViewModel as the Model, but your controller is passing a List

You need to create a view model to represent the search criteria and the results

```
public class EmployeeSearchViewModel
{
    public string EmpId { get; set; }
    public string PAN { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }

    public List<EmpViewModel> Employees { get; set; } = new List<EmpViewModel>();
}
```

then in your controller method:

```
var modelSys = searchRes.ToList();
var viewModel = new EmployeeSearchViewModel 
{
    PAN = get_EmpDetails_Result.pan,
    EmpId = get_EmpDetails_Result.empid,
    Employee = get_EmpDetails_Result.employee
    Employees = modelSys
};
return View(viewModel);
```

In the view:

```
@Model EmployeeSearchViewModel
```

Then your parameters display don't need to pull the EmpID, PAN, etc. from the collection, just from the view model, and you can bind your repeated results to the inner collection "Employees".